# How to enable CORS on paypal SDK API?

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm working with paypal SDK to enable payments, everything was working fine I even tested the code more than 100* times but today I get the following errors in the console: [image: Errors I get in the console]

I did not change anything in my code since it was working:

```
<script>
let total = '{{ order.get_cart_total }}'
// Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
paypal.Buttons({

    style: {
        color: 'blue',
        shape: 'pill',
        label: 'pay',
        height: 50
    },
    // Set up the transaction
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            // ISTO É CÓDIGO ADICIONADO MAIS TARDE
            intent: 'CAPTURE',
            payer: {
                name: {
                    given_name: `{{ user.first_name }}`,
                    surname: `{{ user.last_name }}`
                }
            },
            address: {
                address_line_1: '{{ userAddress.street_address }}',
                address_line_2: '{{ userAddress.apartment_address }}',
                admin_area_2: '{{ userAddress.city }}',
                admin_area_1: '{{ userAddress.state }}',
                postal_code: '{{ userAddress.zip }}',
                country_code: '{{ userAddress.country }}',
            },
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: parseFloat(total).toFixed(2)
                }
            }]
        });
    },
    // Finalize the transaction
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (orderData) {
            let transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
            submitFormData(transaction)
        });
    },
    onCancel: function (data) {
        alert('Something went wrong with the payment.')
    },
    onError: function (err) {
        alert(`${err}`)
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');

function submitFormData(transaction) {
    console.log('Entrou Aqui')

    var url = "/process-order/"
    fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'applicaiton/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'total': total,
                'transaction': transaction
            }),

        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Entrou Aqui tbm')

            // HERE I CHEANGE THE CHECKOUT NAVBAR ACTIVE LINK AND REDIRECT THE USER TO THE "RECEIPT" WRAPPER
            let marker = document.getElementById('marker')
            let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.userNavLink')
            let checkoutWrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('checkout-wrapper')

            marker.style.left = navLinks[2].offsetLeft + 'px'

            checkoutWrappers[1].style.display = 'none'
            navLinks[1].classList.remove('active-link')

            checkoutWrappers[2].style.display = 'flex'
            navLinks[2].classList.add('active-link')
            document.title = navLinks[2].innerText

            // HERE I UPDATE THE CART ICON
            let cartItems = document.getElementById('cartItems')
            cartItems.innerText = 0

            // HERE I DIPLAY SOME DETAILS FROM THE CURRENT TRANSACTION
            let transactionDetails = document.getElementById('transaction-details')
            transactionDetails.innerText = `The transaction with the ID:${transaction.id} was ${transaction.status}
                                    at ${transaction.create_time}`

            // HERE I CHANGE THE RECEIPT CONTAINER ATRIBUTE TO "completed" AND DISABLE THE LINKS
            checkoutWrappers[2].dataset.status = 'completed'
            navLinks[2].style.pointerEvents = 'all'
            navLinks[0].style.pointerEvents = 'none'
            navLinks[1].style.pointerEvents = 'none'
        })
}
```

From what I researched to enable CORS we must make a request on server side but paypal SDK allows for client side and server side integration.

Paypal SDK client side:
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

In my paypal sandbox account the payment is made I just never receive the transaction details back as I usally did.
I've been stuck for hours if someone can help me with this problem it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, the CORS requests failing are not a problem. You can ignore those messages.

The problem is the last line, `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1`.

This means that you are fetching a URL and attempting to parse the result as JSON, but it is not JSON. It is HTML -- something that begins with `<`. This can happen when the URL you are fetching is returning an error page or some other content, instead of the data you expect.

So, you simply need to debug that URL/route on your server and ensure it outputs the correct, expected JSON data -- and not HTML or some error text that your JavaScript code cannot understand or do anything with.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I managed to get it working now.